# How to use AsyncFacebookRunner class

Tags: android, facebook

I am using facebook sdk for my android application. There is a class called AsyncFacebookRunner. I want use this class, but in eclipse it shows that this class is deprecated. I want to know is there any other class to use instead of AsyncFacebookRunner or how can I use AsyncFacebookRunner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Upgrading from 2.0 to 3.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/):

"AsyncFacebookRunner has been deprecated; to execute Requestst asynchronously, use RequestAsyncTask"

Comment: No need to thank me. An upvote or accept would have sufficed ;-)